# Downloadable / Useable Red Alert (2) audio clips?

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert, command-and-conquer-red-alert-2

Anyone know where I can get some useable audio clips from Red Alert aside from recording them directly from the game?

(I'd like to have a "construction complete" quote play after a visual studio build completes.)

Answer (score 5):

I once downloaded an archive called 'Command and Conquer Anniversary Classic Ringtones.rar' containing 7 audio clips from RA, RA2, C&C1 and RA3. I think I downloaded it from the official site.

It doesn't have 'construction complete' though, but other classics like 'Got a present for ya' and 'Shake it baby!'. Since it was free and legal and all that, I'd be happy to give it to you, if you'd like that.

Comment: The file is available on the official [Command & Conquer website](http://portal.commandandconquer.com/portal/site/redalert/downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [XCC Utilities](http://xhp.xwis.net/) in order to extract the sounds you want from the resource files (you want the XCC AV Player and sounds.mix, IIRC).

Comment: Yes, that's the tool modders use. You can extract all sounds from the game with that.